# I am trying to create a react app using the "npx/npm create-react-app hello" command and got this whole message

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

when I run the following command to create a react app:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32> npm i create-react-app -g hello
```

I get the following message in cmd:

```
npm WARN deprecated hello-config@1.0.1: Use @hello/config instead
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
C:\Users\Simran Shivani\AppData\Roaming\npm\create-react-app -> C:\Users\Simran Shivani\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\index.js
C:\Users\Simran Shivani\AppData\Roaming\npm\hello -> C:\Users\Simran Shivani\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\hello\cli\index.js

> core-js@2.6.11 postinstall C:\Users\Simran Shivani\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\hello\node_modules\core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

Thank you for using core-js ( https://github.com/zloirock/core-js ) for polyfilling JavaScript standard library!

The project needs your help! Please consider supporting of core-js on Open Collective or Patreon:
> https://opencollective.com/core-js
> https://www.patreon.com/zloirock

Also, the author of core-js ( https://github.com/zloirock ) is looking for a good job -)


> ejs@2.7.4 postinstall C:\Users\Simran Shivani\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\hello\node_modules\ejs
> node ./postinstall.js

Thank you for installing EJS: built with the Jake JavaScript build tool (https://jakejs.com/)

npm WARN glob-promise@3.4.0 requires a peer of glob@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

+ create-react-app@3.4.1
+ hello@0.3.2
added 379 packages from 242 contributors in 152.381s
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your command tries to install the packages `create-react-app` and `hello` globally, If you are using npm 5.2 or later there is no reason to install `create-react-app` globally.

Use the recommended command to create your app instead,

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

This command will get the latest version of `create-react-app` and generate your project inside a folder name `my-app` in your current working directory without installing `create-react-app` globally.

Then you can change the working directory to `my-app` and start the development server by running the command `npm start`.

You can refer to the [docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/) for more details.